# How to stop a running thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots

```
from pyautogui import moveTo, click, rightClick, write, keyDown, keyUp, hotkey, scroll
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import re
import time
from threading import Thread, Event
import sys

unmutestoploop = Event()
def send(message1):
    pyautogui.moveTo(189, 20, 0.1)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(1000, 960)
    pyautogui.click()
    mes = re.sub('OpenAI', 'BainBan(Ben)', message1)
    mes2 = re.sub('ChatGPT', "Makise Kurisu (MK)", mes)
    pyperclip.copy(mes2)
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
    pyautogui.keyDown("ENTER")
    pyautogui.keyUp("ENTER")

def checkuserperms():
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.moveTo(650, 850)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(1550, 580)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.dragTo(1700, 580, 1)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "c")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    moveTo(1370, 190)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.click()
    copy = pyperclip.paste()
    print(copy)
    if copy == "40 746 499 232" or copy == "40 740 981 295":
        return "yes"
    elif "40" not in pyperclip.paste():
        send("A aparut o eroare in a iti verifica permisiunile, incearca din nou acum xx")

    return "no"
def unmute(time34=1, name1="test"):
    send(f"{name1} isi va lua unmute in {time34}s")
    time.sleep(time34)
    global unmutestoploop
    unmutestoploop.set()
    time.sleep(3)
    moveTo(1000, 200)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    moveTo(1800, 400)
    scroll(-600)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    moveTo(1850, 1000)
    click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    moveTo(1000, 300)
    click()
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.write(f"{name1}")
    time.sleep(1)
    moveTo(1000, 350)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    moveTo(1100, 380)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    click()
    time.sleep(2)
    moveTo(740, 220)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    moveTo(1370, 190)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    click()
    unmutestoploop.clear()
    send(f"{name1} si-a luat unmute")
def mute(name, time2, reason="None"):
    if name == "Beni" or name == "B" or name == "Ben" or name == "Beni Noul" or name == "Marius" or name == "Mari" or name == "M" or name == 'Ma' or name ==  "Mar" or name == "Mariu":
        send("Scuze, n-ai permisiune pentru a face asta xx")
        return
    else:
        pyautogui.moveTo(689, 877, 0.1)
        pyautogui.moveTo(820, 877, 0.1)
        pyautogui.click()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        pyautogui.moveTo(675, 820, 0.1)
        moveTo(1000, 200)
        time.sleep(1)
        click()
        moveTo(1800, 400)
        time.sleep(1)
        scroll(-600)
        moveTo(1850, 1000)
        time.sleep(1)
        click()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        moveTo(1000, 300)
        click()
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.write(f"{name}")
        time.sleep(1)
        moveTo(1000, 350)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        click()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        moveTo(1100, 450)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        click()
        time.sleep(2)
        moveTo(740, 220)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        click()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        moveTo(1370, 190)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        click()
        send(f"{name} si-a luat mute pentru {time2}s motiv: {reason}")
        global thread
        thread = Thread(target=unmute, args=(int(time2), name))
        thread.start()

def ask(what):
    logo = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('2.png')
    print("start")
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.moveTo(500, 10)
    pyautogui.click()
    moveTo(100, 170)
    click()
    pyautogui.moveTo(1000, 930)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyperclip.copy(what)
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
    pyautogui.keyDown("ENTER")
    pyautogui.keyUp("ENTER")
    time.sleep(10)
    try:
        x = logo.left + 10
        y = logo.top + 10
        pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, 0.1)
        pyautogui.click()
    except AttributeError:
        logo = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('copy.png', confidence=0.8)
        x = logo.left + 10
        y = logo.top + 10
        pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, 0.1)
        pyautogui.click()
        if not bool(pyperclip.paste().strip()):
            moveTo(100, 70)
            click()
            time.sleep(4)
            ask()

    return
command = "!"
talk = "!talk"
mute1 = "!mute"
unmute1 = "!unmute"
lastmessacommand = False
stop = "!stop"
def runspccmd(lastmessage):
    global command, talk, mute1, unmute1, lastmessacommand
    if command in lastmessage:
        if talk in lastmessage:
            lastm = str(lastmessage)
            final = lastm.replace('<span>', "")
            final1 = final.replace('!talk', "")
            final2 = final1.replace('</span>', "")
            ask(final2)
            send(pyperclip.paste())
        elif mute1 in lastmessage:
                if checkuserperms() == "no":
                    print("skj")
                    send("Scuze, n-ai permisiune pentru a face asta xx")
                    return
                else:
                    lastm = str(lastmessage)
                    final = lastm.replace('<span>', "")
                    final1 = final.replace('!mute', "")
                    final2 = final1.replace('</span>', "")
                    split = final2.split(" ", 3)
                    print(split)
                    mute(split[1], split[2], split[3])
        elif stop in lastmessage:
            if checkuserperms() == "yes":
                send("Bot oprit ;( Ne mai vedem xx")
                sys.exit("Bot oprit")
            else:
                send("n-ai permisiune sa faci asta xx")
        elif unmute1 in lastmessage:
            if checkuserperms() == "yes":
                try:
                    lastm = str(lastmessage)
                    final = lastm.replace('<span>', "")
                    final1 = final.replace('!unmute', "")
                    final2 = final1.replace('</span>', "")
                    split = final2.split(" ", 2)
                    thread = Thread(target=unmute, args=(int(split[2]), split[1]))
                    thread.start()
                except IndexError:
                    send("eroare, folosire comanda : !unmute nume timp(in secunde)")
            else:
                send("n-ai permisiune sa faci asta xx")
        else:
            send("""Comanda necunoscuta. Comenzi:
            !talk intrebare
            !mute nume secunde motiv
            !unmute nume secunde
            !stop""")



def getlastmessage():
    lm = pyperclip.paste()
    final = lm.replace('<span>', "")
    final2 = final.replace('</span>', "")
    print(final2)
    if "!" in final2:
        runspccmd(final2)
    pyautogui.moveTo(689, 877, 0.1)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.rightClick()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.moveTo(700, 850, 0.1)
    pyautogui.click() 
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.keyDown("F2")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.keyUp("F2")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.moveTo(1900, 140,0.1)
    pyautogui.click()

while True:
    while not unmutestoploop.is_set():
        time.sleep(1.2)
        pyautogui.moveTo(1000, 600)
        pyautogui.scroll(-600)
        getlastmessage()
```

In line 124 I start a thread for a timer unmuting someone, but I also have a command that unmutes, that changes the unmute timer in line 203. How can the thread, if it's running, stop and then I want to start it again at line 203. Help much appreciated it's a bot that just does something based on what commands it receives on whatsapp just a fun project in my free time, I'm not using selenium cuz whatsapp is known for changing their code a lot and I don't want to remake this again.

```
import time
from threading import Thread, Event
unmutestoploop = Event()


def unmute(time34=1, name1="test"):
    print(f"{name1} will get unmuted in {time34}s")
    time.sleep(time34)
    global unmutestoploop
    unmutestoploop.set()
    unmutestoploop.clear()
    print(f"{name1} si-a luat unmute")
def mute(name, time2, reason="None"):
    global thread
    thread = Thread(target=unmute, args=(int(time2), "JJ"))
    thread.start()
while True:
    while not unmutestoploop.is_set():
        time.sleep(1)
        input2 = input("mute or unmute?")
        print("while loop working")
        if input2.lower() == "mute":
            mute("JJ", 5)
        else:
            thread = Thread(target=unmute, args=(int(1), "Person"))
            thread.start()
```

here is a minimal reproducible example, basically if you write mute it will get muted. Then if you write unmute as if to unmute the person he gets unmuted, but then the person is unmuted again if you wrote mute first time.

Comment: I refer you to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, thanks for mentioning. Just added one.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the canonical answer would be to event.wait on some cancel event instead of time.sleep, but I'd recommend considering `sched` here:

```
import sched
import time
import threading


class Mutes:

    def sched_thread(self):
        self.scheduler = sched.scheduler()
        self.scheduler.enter(1, 0, self.keepalive)
        self.scheduler.run()

    def __init__(self):
        self.mutes = {}
        self.scheduler = None
        self.schedthd = threading.Thread(target=self.sched_thread)
        self.schedthd.start()
        self._shutdown = False

    def keepalive(self):
        print("pulse")
        if not self._shutdown:
            self.scheduler.enter(5, 0, self.keepalive)  # Keep scheduler alive

    def add_mute(self, name, mutetime=5):
        print("muting", name)
        self.mutes[name] = self.scheduler.enter(mutetime, 0, lambda: self.remove_mute(name))

    def remove_mute(self, name):
        print("unmuting", name)
        try:
            self.scheduler.cancel(self.mutes[name])
        except (KeyError, ValueError):
            pass  # not an early cancellation, or wasn't muted to begin with.

    def shutdown(self):
        self._shutdown = True
        for mute in self.mutes.values():
            try:
                self.scheduler.cancel(mute)
            except ValueError:
                pass  # probably unnecessary, for threading.
        self.schedthd.join()


mutelist = Mutes()
mutelist.add_mute("Jimmy")
mutelist.add_mute("Sam")
mutelist.remove_mute("Jimmy")
time.sleep(10)
print("Entering Shutdown")
mutelist.shutdown()
print("Done")
```