# How sane is it to use the schedule library in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a sysadmin I know of various way I could schedule the start of a Python script in any OS, and as I'm not really a programmer, I'm working my way towards becoming one.

The `schedule` library in Python is very convenient and suits my needs. I'm trying to figure out if my laziness is damaging my efficiency, in this case.

I've simply put my script inside a function and then I call:

```py
schedule.every(timer_value).minutes.do(func)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is convenient because when I build a Docker image with it, I don't have to deal with cron and for the same reasons I don't have to deal with cron, systemd timers, task scheduler or anything else.

Is it wise to keep the script sleeping until `timer_value` has expired? Or should I just get over my laziness and do it (possibly) properly with any of the services that do this kind of job?

What bad situations could come up doing it like this? For some reason a voice in my head is telling me that using the `scheduler` library is really bad but I don't really know why.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, `cron` or similar system-level tool is going to be far more immune to misbehaving tasks.  If one of your `scheduler` tasks crashes, or gets stuck in an infinite loop, you lose all of the other tasks.

Comment: Consider airflow for an enterprise level solution. However, I have had good success using sched to do things like renew tokens, and have recommended it in past answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76551497/how-to-stop-a-running-thread/76552498#76552498